# How could I use the list data type as a parameter in the Python function?

Tags: python, list, parameters

Currently, I started to learn Python. And I've faced an unclear situation.

For example, I have a piece of Java code:

```
public String myMethod(List<String> listParam, int index) {
String str = listParam.get(index);
return str;
}
```

The question is - how can/should I do the same thing in Python?
Can someone give me the analogy piece of code in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
def myMethod(list_param, index):
    return list_param[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
def myMethod(listParam, index):
    return listParam[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to use the index number on the list variable, the example shown below:

```
# list_variable
name_list = ["foo", "bar", "apple", "orange"]

# using index to get value of respective element 
my_name = name_list[0]
favourite_fruit = name_list[2]

# printing the values
print(my_name)
print(favourite_fruit)

# output
foo
apple
```

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally Python doesn't declare types of variables. Recent versions support (but don't enforce) static type annotations (see [typing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)). The Python interpreter itself doesn't care about the annotations but there are external tools ([mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/)) for checking. Your code would then look like:

```
from typing import List

def myMethod(listParam: List[str], index: int) -> str:
    s: str = listParam[index]
    return s
```